# How to get the part of the string after the 2nd space

Tags: javascript, string

I am having a string like: `$m-set 88829828277 very good he is`. From this string I want to get the part after the second space. ie, I want to get: `very good he is`. 
I tried using `split(" ")[2]` but it only gives one word: `very`.

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could split and join:

```js
const input = '$m-set 88829828277 very good he is';
const splits = input.split(' ');
const output = splits.slice(2).join(' ');
console.log(output);
```

You could also use a regular expression:

```js
const input = '$m-set 88829828277 very good he is';
const output = input.match(/\S+ \S+ (.+)/)[1];
console.log(output);
```

where the `(.+)` puts everything after the second space in a capture group, and the `[1]` accesses the capture group from the match.